# JQuery - How to put new element around a new generated element

Tags: jquery

My script generates a new input field and I want to put a 'span' element around it. But I can't figure out, how to do that.

```
 .append($('<a>').html('+') 
            .attr('href', '#')
            .click(function(){
                ($(this)
                    .after($('<a>').text('X')
                        .attr('href', '#')
                        .click(function(){
                            $(this).parent().remove();
                            return false;   })
                    ) 
                    .after($('<input>') // NEED A SPAN AROUND THIS ELEMENT
                        .attr('type', 'text')
                        .attr("name","avz_anzahl["+avz_array+"][]")
                        .attr("size","3")
                        .attr("style","margin-left:10px; margin-top:5px;")
                        .attr("id","anzahl_feld")
                        .attr("onblur","anzahl_vali();")
                        .attr("value", "")
                    ) 

                    .after('<br/>')).append ;
                return false;   })
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the part like

```
.after($('<span>').html($('<input>')
                        .attr('type', 'text')
                        .attr("name","avz_anzahl["+avz_array+"][]")
                        .attr("size","3")
                        .attr("style","margin-left:10px; margin-top:5px;")
                        .attr("id","anzahl_feld")
                        .attr("onblur","anzahl_vali();")
                        .attr("value", "")
                    ) 
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try JQuery wrap.

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>

    $('.inner').wrap('<div class="new" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your element with the `<span>` element with jQuery's [`.wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method:

```
[yourcodehere].wrap('<span>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wrap function - http://api.jquery.com/wrap/